# Trying to reset all dropdowns except the one that was changed

Tags: jquery

I have 4 dropdowns and when 1 is selected, I want the other 3 to reset to the first option in the dropdown. I have the code below and it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('select').change(function() {

                var current = $(this).attr('id');

                $('select').each(function() {

                    if(!$(this).attr('id') == current) {
                        $('select option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
                    }
                });
            }); 
        });
```

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectCategory.currentCategory}"
        valueChangeListener="#{selectCategory.valueChanged}" id="menu2">
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectCategory.national}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
            oncomplete="loadDataAndCreateChart()" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectCategory.currentCategory}"
        valueChangeListener="#{selectCategory.valueChanged}" id="menu3">
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectCategory.industry}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
            oncomplete="loadDataAndCreateChart()" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectCategory.currentCategory}"
        valueChangeListener="#{selectCategory.valueChanged}" id="menu4">
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectCategory.mayo}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
            oncomplete="loadDataAndCreateChart()" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

equals to

```
<select id="menu1" name="menu1" size="1" onchange="RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{&quot;sourceId&quot;:&quot;menu1&quot;,&quot;parameters&quot;:{&quot;javax.faces.behavior.event&quot;:&quot;valueChange&quot;} } )">  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3Grant</option>

    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select><select id="menu2" name="menu2" size="1" onchange="RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{&quot;sourceId&quot;:&quot;menu2&quot;,&quot;parameters&quot;:{&quot;javax.faces.behavior.event&quot;:&quot;valueChange&quot;} } )"> <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

</select><select id="menu3" name="menu3" size="1" onchange="RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{&quot;sourceId&quot;:&quot;menu3&quot;,&quot;parameters&quot;:{&quot;javax.faces.behavior.event&quot;:&quot;valueChange&quot;} } )"> <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select><select id="menu4" name="menu4" size="1" onchange="RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{&quot;sourceId&quot;:&quot;menu4&quot;,&quot;parameters&quot;:{&quot;javax.faces.behavior.event&quot;:&quot;valueChange&quot;} } )"> <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What debugging steps did you try? What were your results?

Comment: If i put in console.log after `$('select').change(function()`, it doesn't log anything.

Comment: @Catfish: That's not much debugging.

Comment: Could you post your html to help us work out what wasn't working?

Comment: And what html does that code output? jQuery (and JavaScript...) work on the rendered, client-side html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that something like the following *should* work (though it is, as yet, untested):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('select').change(
            function(){
                $('select').not($(this)).find('option:first-child').attr('selected',true);
            })
     });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d4cGL/).

Comment: @Tomalak: not without seeing his html as well, I think. But if that's posted, I'll certainly *try*.

Comment: My guess is $('select option:eq(0)') - because even though it's inside his 'each' loop, it wouldnt apply to the current select element being iterated over, but would repeatedly apply to the first select element in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Working example:

```
  $('select').change(function() {
            $('select').not(this).children('option:first-child').prop('selected',true);
  });
```

Make sure to use `prop()` if you have jQuery >=1.6, else stick with attr('selected',true)

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/dDXA6/

Comment: Just use `attr` instead of `prop` like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

By

```
if(!$(this).attr('id') == current) {
   $('select option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
}
```

did you mean

```
if ($(this).attr('id') != current) {
   $(this).find('option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
}
```

?

Comment: Yes I did, but there was still other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Tomalak's probably on the right track with your option statement, but try combining it with a `.not()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        $('select').not($(this)).each(function() {
            $('option:eq(0)',this).attr('selected', true);
        });
    }); 
});
```

it doesnt change your conditional statement, but it cuts out a lot of code.